# C++ VSCode how to link miniz

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I tried what';s written in their docs:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
./vcpkg install miniz
```

And then in my cpp

```
#include "miniz.h"
```

But I still get cannot open source file "miniz.h"

Any idea please?

Comment: `vcpkg integrate install` I think this works with Visual Studio Community and does nothing for VSCode. For VSCode you probably want to use CMake and the CMakeTools extension.

Comment: how cn I link then not using this ?

Comment: After installation you will have to edit your args: in tasks.json (which is in the documentation I linked) to have your application link to the library. The include and linker paths will already be set since pacman installs in the compiler's folders.

Comment: And adding  "${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/miniz/" in my c_cpp_properieties.json under "includePath" does not work ?

Comment: `c_cpp_properieties.json` is just for Intellisense. It's not for building.

Comment: i added                 "-I ${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/miniz/" under "args"
 in my task.json, but still does not work

Comment: You need more than the include directory. You need the linker path and to link to the library which should have a `.a` extension.

Comment: If you installed via pacman. The include directory and path for linking are not necessary because the compiler already looks in the path that pacman installs its packages into. You will still have to link to the library like I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: I did sudo apt get pacman, then pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-minizip-ngand it launch the game pacman,..

Comment: And if I do sudo apt install pacman-package-manager 
I get Unable to locate package pacman-package-manager

Comment: `sudo apt get pacman` suggests a Unix based, probably debian, system. Because  you got started using Windows package installation tools, @drescherjm made the logical assumption you were using a Windows-based system. Most of his advice goes out the window if you're using Unix. You likely want something like `sudo apt-get install miniz`, but a debian-based system should already have a couple built-in zipping libraries you can use.

Comment: But I want miniz to include in my code though. Or anything to unzip in c++ cause i've thousands of files...

Comment: Please first add the OS, distribution, and version of your build system. This will greatly colour the answers you get.

Comment: That said if I'm right  about a Unix-based system, [zlib](https://www.zlib.net/) should get you where you need to go and is probably already installed. If you have trouble with it, Mark Adler is a regular contributor here at Stack Overflow, and if he can't help you, no one can.

Comment: Looks like miniz is very closely related to zlib, being it's hosted on Marks's zlib github.

Comment: I've successfully linked zlib. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted most of my comments because the vcpkg made me think you were on MS Windows and using MinGW.